# Generate PDF with mojolicious

Tags: pdf, mojolicious

iam looking for generate PDF with mojolicious. I found [this](https://github.com/Tekki/mojolicious_pdf-reportwriter_example) example. But when run, show :

> Can't locate object method "render_partial" via package "MojoRwr::Composer" at /usr/local/share/perl/5.22.1/Mojolicious.pm line 146.

I ran the REQUIREMENTS. I do not know why it does not work Somebody can help me please.

My pc is ubuntu server 16
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`render_partial` was replaced with `render_to_string` a long time ago. With that simple change, the application works...